# Vuejs global text snippets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to handle global text blocks in Vuejs, such as validation error messages or something like success messages that are used in multiple components. The .env file does not seem to me to be the right place for it. Perhaps someone knows the best practice for this "problem".

Comment: You can add them on the `window` object or use a mixin.

Comment: I've done it in a separate file called "messages.js"
export default {
  ERROR_500: 'Try again later..',
};
Thanks!